# WebStorm Terminal Color - Linux

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a couple of issues with my terminal colors in WebStorm that I have been unable to resolve by using `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Colors`

**I am running:**
Kubunutu 20.04,
WebStorm 2021.2 64 bit for linux. Build #WS-212.1746.80

**My issues are:**

1. In the interactive console color interface, the 'console' background does not match my actual console background. Mine is dark, the interactive settings one is white. The result of this is that I am unable to see how my color selections will actually appear.
2. Hyperlinks in my console are displayed in the default blue (000FF), which works fine against a white background but is unreadable against a dark background. I have been unable to locate the setting for this. They do not appear to be in the console colors section. And if  I go to `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Hyperlinks` there are plenty of options, but none of them seem to affect what goes on in the terminal.

**Questions:**

How do I get the console color selector background to match my actual background selection?

Where do I access the setting that determines the hyperlink color in the WebStorm terminal in Linux?

**Screenshots follow:**

Here you can see that my background is set to dark, but the color selector interface background is white.

[image: Color selector not matching selected background color]

And here you can see the unreadable hyperlinks that I can't read. The command to get this screen was `npm fund`

[image: WebStorm console unreadable hyperlinks]

Here are my actual console colors:

[image: actual console colors]

Here you can see the hyperlink settings, with background set to yellow, and the actual hyperlinks displayed behind, demonstrating that these two things are not linked. (I refreshed the terminal display after changing the settings)

[image: Hyperlink colors]

Comment: You can inspect *.icls* file via _Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors | Gear Icon | Export | IntelliJ IDEA Color Scheme_ and find *CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_KEY* key and its value. Does it match what you specified?

Comment: It is the same. That is evidently not the value that controls it. I did manage to change it by tweaking a value called "TEXT" but that also changes the Editor background, which for me is undesirable. But at least I am closer to solving the mystery. I think the selector screen inherits from TEXT if no value is set or maybe it's one and the same. In every color scheme I tried they matched. So maybe it's one setting for both. I'm hoping not... But if it is, at least now I know how to temporarily change it.